# VBA IF function error

Tags: excel, vba, function, if-statement

I want to insert the following  formula to a cell

```
Range("Q12").FormulaR1C1 = "=If(P12>1,1,P12)"
```

but my output in the cell is below

```
=WENN('P12'>1;1;'P12')
```

the problem is it includes **' '** . Please help me to correct this problem

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the non-R1C1 format:

```
Sub hfdjs()
    Range("Q12").Formula = "=If(P12>1,1,P12)"
End Sub
```